# Get html button id and store it for next page

Tags: php, html

OK, so is there anyway to get the button id when clicked and store it for use in the next page (i'm trying to use the button id to know which button is clicked and use it for an sql query in the next page) ?
here's my code :

```
        while($donnees=$reponse->fetch())
        {
          ?>
                        <tr>
                            <form action="suppression.php" method="post">
                                <td ><h3 ><a ><?php echo $donnees['Ncheque']; ?></a></h3></td>
                                <td><?php echo $donnees['Dateremise'];?></td>
                                <td><a><?php echo $donnees['Client'];?></a></td>
                                <td><a><?php echo $donnees['Banque'];?></a></td>
                                <td><a><?php echo $donnees['Motif'];?></a></td>
                                <td><?php echo $donnees['Dateretour'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $donnees['Datedelivrance'];?></td>                                   
                                <td><input type="submit" id="<?php echo $donnees['Ncheque'] ?>" class="button" name="delete" value="supprimer" /><a href="#" class="ico modifier">modifier</a></td>

                            </form> 
                        </tr>
            <?php 
        }
        $reponse->closeCursor();
        ?>
```

Comment: You could attach an onSubmit event on the button to modifiy a hidden field with this id of the submitting button.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap each button in a `<form>` element and specify the GET parameter directly in the `action` then in PHP check which button was clicked using `$_GET`.

#### First Page

```
<form action='otherPage.php?button=Button1'><button>Button1</button><form>
<form action='otherPage.php?button=Button2'><button>Button2</button><form>
```

#### Second Page

```
<?php
if($_GET['button']=="Button1"){
  echo "Button 1 was clicked";
} else if($GET['button']=="Button2"){
  echo "Button 2 was clicked";
} else {
  echo "No button was clicked";
}
```

Comment: The thing is I don't know how many buttons i might get, it all depends on how many rows the page fetches from the database

Comment: So then generate this dynamically

Comment: I keep getting undefined index error, what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 localstorage.
It stores values in key value pair in your browser.

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value'); // in place of value give id of the clicked button
```